# How do I prove that the intersection of all $A_j$ is non-empty?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $A_j \subseteq X, j = 1, 2,\dots, N$ some sets of size $k$ each, different from each other and such that the intersection of any $k + 1$ of the sets $Aj$ is non-empty. How do I prove that the intersection of all $A_j$ is non-empty?

The solution I came up with is to start with the claim that the intersection of all $A_j$ is empty. If $A_1 = \{x_1, x_2,\dots, x_k\}$, then because the intersection of any $k + 1$ of the sets $A_j$ is non-empty, there will be some set from $A_2,\dots, A_N$ that don't include $x_1$, that don't include $x_2$ etc, then the claim that the intersection of all $A_j$ is empty is wrong. So, the intersection of all $A_j$ is non-empty. Do you think this is correct, or should I think of something else?

Comment: Don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is generally right but you need some details to make sure it’s rigorous.

Assume for the sake of contradiction that the intersection of everything is empty. Let $B$ be one of the sets with $B=\{ x_1,...x_k\}$. Then for each $i$ there is some set $A_i$ with $x_i$ not in $A_i$, since no $x_i$ is in all sets. Then, the intersection of $B$ and $A_1$,...,$A_k$ is empty since it doesn’t have any $x_i\in B$ due to $A_i$ and doesn’t have anything that’s not in $B$. However, these are $k+1$ sets with empty intersection contradicting the properties of this set of sets.

Comment: Eric, thank you for your responce but I have a question. The variable i you are using, is the same variable as j?

Comment: I’m indexing a new group of $k$ sets whose indices are unrelated to the original indices of sets (since there is no import to the original ordering of the sets).